# Find an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, similar-matrices, permutation-matrices

Find an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}=B$, where

$$A =   \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix},
\qquad
B =     \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

I know that:

- $A$ can be transformed to $B$ by first switching the first two rows, then the first two columns,
- permutation matrices are orthogonal.

But I am unable to proceed further in order to find matrix $P$. Please help me to solve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What permutation matrix $P$ has the effect of swapping the first two rows of a matrix $A$ in the product $PA$?*

This, and what you have written, immediately leads to the answer:
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Why are you not taking $P^{-1}$ into account? Just $PA$ suffices?

Comment: And how did you directly get $P$? Trial and error?

Comment: @s1mple Since permutation matrices are orthogonal, $P^{-1}=P^T$. It turns out that $P$ is its own transpose, and hence $P$ is its own inverse, and hence $AP$ swaps the first two columns of $A$ as you wrote.

Comment: @s1mple I got $P$ from your description.